# Leer XML en PostgresSQL

Tags: postgresql, xml

¡Se pretende obtener la información del xml, el error es que no me retorna nada! Al modificar el XML y quitar el espacio de nombres “cfdi:” funciona correctamente y me trae los datos del nodo que se está especificando en la consulta

**La consulta sql**

```
SELECT xmltable.*
FROM desarrollo.tbl_x tx ,
   XMLTABLE ('/Comprobante/Conceptos/Concepto' PASSING x
             COLUMNS
                id FOR ORDINALITY,
                ClaveProdServ text PATH '@ClaveProdServ' NOT null,
                Cantidad      text path '@Cantidad',
                NoIdentificacion   text PATH '@NoIdentificacion' NOT null,
                ClaveUnidad   text PATH '@ClaveUnidad' NOT null,
                Descripcion   text PATH '@Descripcion' NOT null,
                ValorUnitario text PATH '@ValorUnitario' NOT null,
                Importe       text PATH '@Importe' NOT null,
                Descuento     text PATH '@Descuento' NOT null);
```

**El XML**

```
    <cfdi:Comprobante xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3 http://www.sat.gob.mx/sitio_internet/cfd/3/cfdv33.xsd" Version="3.3" Serie="X" Folio="78" Fecha="2019-12-16T12:00:49" 
        CondicionesDePago="CONTADO" SubTotal="6422.14" Descuento="1957.96" Moneda="MXN" TipoCambio="1" Total="4464.18" TipoDeComprobante="I" MetodoPago="PUE" LugarExpedicion="54700" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:cfdi="http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3">
        <cfdi:Emisor Rfc="XAXX010101000" Nombre="EMPRESA X" RegimenFiscal="603" />
        <cfdi:Receptor Rfc="XAXX010101000" Nombre="PERSONA X" UsoCFDI="G03" />
        <cfdi:Conceptos>
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000100080001 01/2016-12/2016 REZAGO PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="1093.14" Importe="1093.14" Descuento="0.00" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000900020001 01/2016-12/2016 RECARGOS PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="849.36" Importe="849.36" Descuento="849.36" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000100080001 01/2017-12/2017 REZAGO PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="1100.16" Importe="1100.16" Descuento="0.00" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000900020001 01/2017-12/2017 RECARGOS PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="610.59" Importe="610.59" Descuento="610.59" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000100080001 01/2018-12/2018 REZAGO PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="1107.84" Importe="1107.84" Descuento="0.00" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000900020001 01/2018-12/2018 RECARGOS PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="368.91" Importe="368.91" Descuento="368.91" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000100010001 01/2019-12/2019 PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="1163.04" Importe="1163.04" Descuento="0.00" />
            <cfdi:Concepto ClaveProdServ="93151500" NoIdentificacion="78" Cantidad="1" ClaveUnidad="E48" Descripcion="4001000000001000000000000900020001 01/2019-12/2019 RECARGOS PREDIAL" ValorUnitario="129.10" Importe="129.10" Descuento="129.10" />
        </cfdi:Conceptos>

    </cfdi:Comprobante>
```

**El resultado**

[image: Debería devolver la tabla llena]

Comment: Puedes explicar exactamente cual es el problema?

Comment: @Merling Samuel Sobalvarro    ¡Se pretende obtener la información del xml, el error es que no me retorna nada!
Al modificar el XML y quitar el espacio de nombres “cfdi:” funciona correctamente y me trae los datos del nodo qué se esta especificando en la consulta

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Debes poner tu mismo el `namespace` necesario, algo así:

```
  SELECT xmltable.*
FROM desarrollo.tbl_x tx ,
   XMLTABLE ( XMLNAMESPACES('http://www.sat.gob.mx/cfd/3' AS i),
    '/i:Comprobante/i:Conceptos/i:Concepto' PASSING x
             COLUMNS
                id FOR ORDINALITY,
                ClaveProdServ text PATH '@ClaveProdServ' NOT null,
                Cantidad      text path '@Cantidad',
                NoIdentificacion   text PATH '@NoIdentificacion' NOT null,
                ClaveUnidad   text PATH '@ClaveUnidad' NOT null,
                Descripcion   text PATH '@Descripcion' NOT null,
                ValorUnitario text PATH '@ValorUnitario' NOT null,
                Importe       text PATH '@Importe' NOT null,
                Descuento     text PATH '@Descuento' NOT null);
```

Y obtendrás algo como esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]